# Is there any other way to say 'Sent Successfully'?

Tags: word-usage

The actual message is 'Message was sent successfully'. But, we are not sure that the message was delivered to the person or the person has read the message. Is the use of 'sent successfully' correct?

Comment: No. Technically *send* implies only the dispatch from the point of origin.  It does not include transmission, receipt, acknowledgment and so on. Is that what the question is about?

Comment: I'm with @Kris on this one, except I would change his "no" into a "yes". Yes, this usage is correct, precisely because "sent" means "sent" and does not include transmission, receipt, acknowledgment and so on. "Sent" does not mean "delivered", only "delivered" means "delivered".

Comment: @Kris Thanks for the reply. Yes that's what the question is about. Just wanted to confirm whether sent is the correct there.

Comment: Elvis has left the building. (Where he is now is anyone's guess.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the use of "sent successfully" is correct because when we talk about sending messages, we only refer to the action of message being sent from our location / email etc.

This does not include notifications regarding delivery or message read receipts.

There are separate features and thus separate messages for such notifications.

For example:

"Your message has been delivered" (Confirming delivery to the recipient)

"Your message has been read" (Confirming that message has been read by the recipient)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "sent successfully", we have the word *delivered* which means or should mean that it safely arrived to its rightful recipient.

Comment: Not in all cases will "sent" also be a confirmation about "delivery". They could be two different notifications in different systems.

Comment: I think you are misparsing my English here. I'm not making any claim about what send implies vis-a-vis successful delivery. I am stating the "delivered" means confirmed all the way to arrival to the recipient.

Comment: Yeah, got your point.